# Regex password validation working fine on regex verification sites but not on mine

Tags: asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following Regex code that works fine on regex verification code but not on my website (built with ASP.NET MVC). It validates the length and numeric but not the absence of special characters.

My regex: `/^(?=.*[!@@#$&](?=.*[A-Z]))(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}$/`

On my website Toto1234 is considered fine but that does not be the case since it does not contain a special character.

Comment: Can you provide some specific examples of what the pattern should/shouldn't match? Because the pattern you've given above doesn't match `Toto1234`, and won't match every possible password that fits the (rather poorly worded) rules you've given.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz, Thanks for pointing this out. I re-wrote it to cover all special characters. here it is: ^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z]).{8,}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I was checking on my view but did not make any change on my model. My model had a Regex that was not checking for special characters. But on my view, there is script that checks if the password matches the regex.

Edit: The solution, to be more clear is to make sure the view model or class is decorated with the right Regex. Any regex check and/or validation in the view my work temporary before you try to submit your form.

In my case since I had to different regex (in my view --via jquery-- and my model), client side verification worked because I have the right regex. But server side verification did not. I had to make sure I had the right regex on my class as well.

Hope this is more clear.

Comment: SO is not a forum. Please provide specific information as to how you resolved your problem so that others may benefit, and mark the question as "answered" using the checkmark.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz, I know SO is not a forum. You don't need to remind me that. The issue was not in the regex I posted but in my code. And it is asp.net MVC related. so if you have a background in MVC, I think you might have understood what I said. I will update my answer but I am wondering what kind of details are you expecting.